# Dropped iPad turns off by itself

Tags: ios, itunes, ipad

I dropped my iPad and now it turns itself off.

It says to connect to iTunes.  I look this up but the answers say to connect to a computer.  I don't have a computer to connect this to.

Is there a way to fix this without connecting to a computer?

Comment: It sounds like it's physically damaged. I'm afraid there's nothing you can do except take it to a repairer.

Comment: What fix are you seeking? Remedying a physical break inside the iPad never gets fixed by connecting to a computer so could you explain what “this fix” entails?

Answer (score 1):

if the iPad isn't broken, you are going to need to process a DFU wipe.

unfortunately you will need a computer running a current version of iTunes, if you follow the processes described here:

> 1. Connect the device to a computer using a USB cable.
> 2. Hold down both the Home button and Lock button.
> 3. After 8 seconds, release the Lock button while continuing to hold down the Home button.
> 4. If the Apple logo appears, the Lock button was held down for too long.
> 5. Nothing will be displayed on the screen when the device is in DFU mode. If open, iTunes will alert you that a device was detected in
>      recovery mode.
> 6. If your device shows a screen telling you to connect the device to iTunes, retry these steps.

([Source](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/DFU_Mode))